# Cast from "UITableViewCell" to unrelated type "UICollectionView" always fails

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

Actually I am trying to add CollectionView in TableViewCell but I am not able to handel it as you can see in case of adding TableView in TableViewCell works fine but in case of Collection view it shows error.
See the screen shot for your reference.

Can you please suggest how to fix this error.

[image]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Traffic") {
        tableView.registerClass(TrafficCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TrafficCollectionView")
        let TrafficCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TrafficCollectionView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrafficCollectionViewCell
        print("im in Traffic Cell")
        TrafficCell.TrafficArray = dataArray[indexPath.row]["detail"].arrayObject!
        TrafficCell.TrafficCollectionView.reloadData()
        TrafficCell.TrafficViewController = self
        return TrafficCell
    }


   else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "News") {
        tableView.registerClass(NewsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewsTableViewCell")
        let NewsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
        print("Im in News Cell")
        NewsCell.NewsArray = dataArray[indexPath.row]["detail"].arrayObject!
        NewsCell.NewsTableView.reloadData()
        NewsCell.NewsTableViewController = self
        return NewsCell
    }

    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Category") {
        tableView.registerClass(CategoryTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell")
        let CategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CategoryTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        print("Im in Category Cell")
        CategoryCell.CategoryArray = dataArray[indexPath.row]["detail"].arrayObject!
        CategoryCell.CategoryTableView.reloadData()
        CategoryCell.CategoryTableViewController = self
        return CategoryCell
    }
```

Comment: You need to add the `collectionVIew` inside `TableViewCell` and return the object of that customTableViewCell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I am doing the same process which you have mentioned.

Comment: Check properly other wise this error never show. May be you have declare `TrafficCollectionViewCell : UICollectionView` instead of `TrafficCollectionViewCell : UITableViewCell`.

Comment: your warning means, that you cannot force the UITableViewCell to be a TrafficCollectionViewCell. dequeReuseble cell is returning a UITableViewCell! and not AnyObject. So if you want to cast it, make guard let cell = degree ... as? TrafficCollectionViewCell, and this will as well fix the error i think

Comment: oh and you don't need to register the classes all the time, just do it once in the viewDidLoad or so